# JAVA way to count how many getters in bean that are not null

Tags: java

Ok I have a bean list and I can do `beans.size()` to get how many rows I got.....but I need to dynamically know how many columns of data I have before I send to the jsp.

The maximum # of getters I have in the bean is 10....

Is there a way to do this??

Would I have to do a loop on the list and do a `If` check on all the getters and increment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a loop. From what you write - you are probably abusing beans (treating them like maps or other structures that have dynamic keys).